# How to make a JavaScript function control two HTML IDs?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this button tag element

```
<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" onclick="contentDownloads()">
<img src="./downloads/content-textures.svg" width="120px" />
</button>
```

And has a javascript function

```
      function contentDownloads() {
        var x = document.getElementById("vipDownloads");
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
        }
      }
```

But, in the future I will include more buttons and would lead to the same function.

This is the part that contains the IDs:

```
<div id="vipDownloads" class="collapse show" style="display: none;">     
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">Map Pack v 1.8 <span class="caption-entry">by cWaLker</span> </h5>
<p class="card-text">
Aight Fellas,
Map Pack v 1.8 introduces some revived classics and under the radar stunners. <br>
<br> 1.7 went on a diet and dropped some restraining pounds.
For this nugget to work stable, you'd need to remove your own user folder first and then drop the User folder from the 1.8 bulk package.. it will serve you everything you need anyways ;-)<br>
<br> Have Fun Guys lets kick some flips!              
</p>
<a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SNivhvHi-4PjPDy1tob-91HYs3x3R_z9" target="_blank"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Download</button></a><br>           
</div>
</div>
```

You can see here how I designed the buttons and content http://thpsblog.000webhostapp.com/downloads.html (the css on my host takes a while to actually update, might include some white on white colors)

The function hides and unhides content.

I have found some solutions but they were all typed in jQuery, and unfortunately I do not know jQuery.

How could I make this function take two unique ids?

Comment: What you really should do is get rid of your inline `onclick="whateverMethod()"` and learn how to use [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) — the eventListener gets the _event_ as a parameter and you can find what exactly was clicked from `event.target` ... you can _attach_ the event listener to several things based on the two (multiple) unique ids (or non-unique classes) and it can do things such as `event.target.style.display = "block";`

Comment: Nice. i'll see what i can do as my experience right now is limited. Thanks so much for replying.

Answer (score 2):

Make the ID of the element to toggle a parameter of the function, and pass it when you call the function.

```js
function contentDownloads(id) {
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" onclick="contentDownloads('vipDownloads')">
<img src="./downloads/content-textures.svg" width="120px" />
</button>
```

Comment: do i pass in the id as an argument?

Comment: Yes, can't you see that in `onclick="contentDownloads('vipDownloads')"`?

Comment: Yes, i just don`t know if it goes on the function or the var of the function, for future id's

Comment: Sorry i am not implementing this the right way because its just not doing it for the other button.

Comment: The other button should have `onclick="contentDownloads('someOtherId')"`

Comment: Your question isn't really very clear. What do you really want each button to do with each ID?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to add an `onclick` event to your html, you can create a vars array and use a forEach loop. Else, you can use @Barmar's answer.

```
function contentDownloads() {
  var x = document.getElementById("vipDownloads");
  var y = document.getElementById("y");
  var z = document.getElementById("z");

  vars = [x,y,z]; // update this array when selected a new element

  vars.forEach(function(p){
      if (p.style.display === "none") {
    p.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    p.style.display = "none";
  }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make id param as others suggested or use data attributes:

```
<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" onclick="contentDownloads(this)" data-downloadsid="vipDownloads">
<img src="./downloads/content-textures.svg" width="120px" />
</button>
```

```
function contentDownloads(element) {
        var x = document.getElementById(element.dataset.downloadsid);
        if(x == null) return;
        if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
        }
   }
```

Comment: `this` isn't passed automatically when you use `onclick="..."`. You need to pass it as an explicit argument, e.g. `contentDownloads(this)`

Comment: @Barmar Exactly, thank you, used to add handlers via scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the elements with a class and iterate each

```
<div class="download-element">Element 1</div>
<div class="download-element">Element 2</div>
<div class="download-element">Element 3</div>

<button class="btn btn-link" type="button" onclick="contentDownloads()">
<img src="./downloads/content-textures.svg" width="120px" />
</button>
```

```
function contentDownloads() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.download-element')
        .forEach(element => {
            if(element.style.display === "none") {
                element.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                element.style.display = "none";
            }
        })
}
```